# Making VSCode and IntelliJ breadcrumb UX consistent

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

For work, I use both VSCode and IntelliJ.

These editors have a feature called "Breadcrumbs" which shows the directory path to the current file and structure of the nesting around the currently selected element above the editor.

You can use the Breadcrumbs to navigate easily to nearby files. It's a great feature and I use it heavily!

The problem is: VSCode and IntelliJ have a slightly different user experience here. In VSCode, clicking on an item in the breadcrumbs pops up the list of *siblings* of that item. In IntelliJ, clicking on an item in the breadcrumbs pops up the list of *children* of that item.

Switching back and forth between these experiences is really confusing!

I've been searching in vain to see if either editor can be configured to work like the other one. I haven't found any preferences, sadly. But maybe I'm missing where to look for this?